# How to specify favicon while showing jpeg only

Tags: http

Niewbie here, please be kind.
I run a small website.  I want to specify a favicon while showing jpeg image only (no html description).

Question:
  From which directry the favicon is fetched when a jpeg is requested 
  to be sent?

I have a http-root directry where I placed favicon1.
Under the root, there is a directry of group1, where there is favicon2.
Under the group1, there is a directry named pictures. 
In the pictures directry, there are jpeg image files, and favicon2 file again.

When one of the image files (and the file only) is requested by:
  http://(root)/group1/pictures/aaa.jpg
the favicon1 is sent together, not favocon2.
I want favicon2 to be sent.

(Is it httpd specific?)

Tak

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="pathToFavIconFolder/favicon.png">
```

In your case i guess,`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="group1/pictures/favicon2.jpg">`

Answer (score 0):

If the image is loaded alone, not as part of a HTML page, there is no way to specify the favicon. Browsers will either show the image itself as the favicon, appropriately scaled down, or perhaps load `/favicon.ico` from the root of the website. There isn't any way for you to control this.

The only real solution, then, is not to load the image alone, but to create a simple HTML page which contains the image. This page can then also contain a `<link>` to your desired favicon, as usual.